# How to make a button on-click to go to another page using HTML?

Tags: html, button, hyperlink

I have a button, when you click the button it will take you to one of my sub-sites.

The button is a child element of a `a` tag. Is there a better way?

```
<a target='_blank' href='example.com/sub-site.html'>
<button name='link' style="cursor:pointer"  class='example-style' value='example.com/sub-site'
title='Example Title>Example</button></a>
```

If possible, I'll prefer not to use the `form` tag.

Thanks!

Comment: Why you don't use the a href target directly instead of button inside a tag?

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to redirect.
An example is shown here:

```
<button id="button1">Example</button>
<script>
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function() {
    window.location.href = "example.com/sub-site";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `href` directly inside the `<button>` tag:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href = 'example.com/sub-site.html';">Example</button>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

if your question is what is better "a href..." or "button...: I will tell you that for me it is the "a href"  because  the redirection is explicit.